# Display posts in row Horizontally

Tags: posts, get-row

On index.php page, I am showing only thumbs and two custom fields. How can I set specific number of posts in one row like this one; http://www.whatmobile.com.pk

Comment: This is pretty much a **CSS** question, rather than a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**: build a [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) that loads the posts you want. Note: you can number the limit of results using the `posts_per_page` parameter.

**Step 2**: style the posts using CSS. Give each post box a width and float them to the left.